# How can it be proven that the graph of the function $y=x^3-15x^2+48x-3$ intersects the $x$-axis three times?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

How can it be proven that the graph of the function $y=x^3-15x^2+48x-3$ intersects the $x$-axis three times?
Help will be much appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: find three changes of sign, and invoke the IVT.

Comment: IVT is likely not available for precalc. Oh wait, it was calculus also.

Comment: Try looking up Descartes rule of signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider the derivative $y'=3 x^2-30 x+48$ you see that it has two values where $y'=0$ namely $x=2$ where $y=41$ and $x=8$ where $y=-67$

As $y''=6x-30$ we have $y''(2)=-18$ so $(2,41)$ is a maximum and $y''(8)=18$ so $(8,-67)$ is a minimum. Therefore the function must cross the $x$-axis once before $x=2$ a second time between $x=2$ and $x=8$ and a third time after $x=8$.

Actual roots  approximations are $x_1=0.0637652,\;x_2=4.51427,\;x_3=10.422$

Hope this can help

[image]

Comment: Again,this is where a graphing software package is VERY helpful for checking your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^3-15x^2+48x-3.$

Thus,
$$f'(x)=3(x^2-10x+16)=3(x-8)(x-2).$$

Hence, $x_{min}=8$ and $x_{max}=2$

and since $f$ is a continuous function,  $f(2)=41>0$ and $f(8)=-67<0$, we are done!

Because $f$ increases on $(-\infty,3]$, $f$ decreases on $[2,8]$ and $f$ increases on $[8,+\infty)$.

Also, we can use the following reasoning.

$f(0)<0$ and $f(1)>0$, which says that there is a root on $(0,1)$;

$f(5)<0$, which says that there is another root on $(1,5)$ and
$f(11)>0$, which says that there is another root on $(5,11)$.

Id est, we proved that $f$ has three distinct roots.

But $f$ can not have more roots.

Thus, $f$ has three roots exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you explain more in detail? I didn't understand what the extrema points have to do with finding the roots of the function.

Comment: @Blabla I added something. See now.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach. It is straightforward to check that the polynomial $q(x)=x^3-15x^2+48x$ has three real roots, since the discriminant of $x^2-15x+48$ is positive. The value of $q(x)$ at the stationary point $x=2$ equals $44$ and the value of $q(x)$ at the stationary point $x=8$ equals $-64$.  It follows that $q(x)-3$ has three real roots just like $q(x)$, since it changes its sign over the intervals $(-\infty,2),(2,8),(8,+\infty)$.